# Proof of probability of a value lying between $\pm \sigma$ from the mean of a gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I wish to show that the likelihood of a value lying between $\pm\sigma$ from the mean of a Gaussian distribution is $\approx 68.2\%$. The Gaussian distribution function is given by 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\bigg(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)$$
Centering this about the mean and integrating from $-\sigma$ to $\sigma$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\exp\bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)\ \mathrm{d}x$$
Defining an integral, $I$ to be 
$$I=\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\exp\bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg) \ \mathrm{d}x$$we can write
$$I^2=\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\exp\bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg) \ \mathrm{d}x\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\exp\bigg(-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg) \ \mathrm{d}y$$
$$=\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x^2+y^2)\bigg)\mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y$$
Converting to polar coordinates
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sigma}r\exp\bigg(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)\ \mathrm{d}r\ \mathrm{d}\theta$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\bigg[-\sigma^2\exp\bigg(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)\bigg]_0^\sigma\ \mathrm{d}\theta$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\sigma^2-\sigma^2\exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\ \mathrm{d}\theta$$
$$=2\pi\sigma^2\bigg(1-\exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg)$$
So the original integral can be calcualted
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\exp\bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)\ \mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{1-e^{-1/2}}$$
However this gives a value of $\approx 0.627$ or $62.7\%$, which is not the desired value. Can anyone help me as to where I've gone wrong?

Comment: One problem: before you convert to polar coordinates, your region of integration is a square with side length $\sigma$, but after you convert, the region is now a circle with radius $\sigma$.

Comment: @Zachary Thanks, I'd say does this mean that the limits of integration should be from $0$ to $2\sigma$ or $-\sigma$ to $\sigma$, however neither of these yield the correct result. Is polar coordinates not the way to go about solving this integral then?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this integral in closed form. You can make the substitution $u=x/\sigma$ to eliminate $\sigma$ from the integrand and bounds and get something you can integrate numerically.

Comment: The normal distribution is $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$ Using the formula as originally written above, the value of the integral will depend on $\sigma$ and will have the desired value only when $\sigma=2.$

Comment: One way to do the integral could be to write the exponential function as a series and integrate termwise. It might take several terms to get to three digits of precision, however.